# bash script : is it possible to recognize video format from files (to batch extract audio from them)?

Tags: bash, scripts, avconv

I have written a little bash script to extract audio from video files in batch mode.

Sound is extracted from each mp4 file to flac format using avconv (and the flac codec).

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Batch conversion of audio extraction from video

FOLDER_SRC="/home/Me/Music/TestBatchConv"

for myvid in $(find ${FOLDER_SRC} | grep mp4)
do
avconv -i $myvid -acodec flac "${myvid}.flac"
done

exit 0
```

It works fine, but I would like to improve it.

The script only detects mp4 format. Is it possible to recognize a video file with a command (instead of testing each video format) ?

Thank you for advices.

Comment: 1] If you only had videos in a folder, would you then need to grep for mp4? 2] Why are you going for flac? Aren't those files huge?

Comment: 1) yes you are right. in fact the script was not working because i have the TestBatchConv.sh~ file in it (not the script file itself). I can suppress this file but the question still remains :) and 2) sure ogg or mp3 would be more suitable.

Comment: I use `ffmpeg -y -i "$1" -c:a copy "$2"`. It seems to work for all video formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `file`

e.g.

```
 $ file -b 01--Frank_Sinatra--Close_to_You_And_More--Close_to_You.m4a 
 Audio file with ID3 version 2.4.0, contains: ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, iTunes AAC-LC
```

It should cover all well-known media types.
If something is missing, you can add it yourself (see `man magic`).

Comment: thx for your answer, I tried `file -b` with several video files and it returns `Macromedia Flash Video` but also `ISO Media, MPEG v4 system, version 2` for eg. So I can grep for Video or Media, and it would be suitable for my usage, but I am not 100% it contains all videos format :)

Comment: @riimzzai see update in answer

Comment: okay thx (`file -i` works too but strangely recognize mkv as application)

Answer (score 2):

To test in Bash, if $file is a video file, you could use

```
[[ $(ffprobe -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -print_format csv=p=0 "$file") ]] && echo $file is video
```

`ffprobe` is provided by ffmpeg package. Ubuntu 14.04 does not have ffmpeg in standard repositories, but you could add ppa:mc3man/trusty-media repository and install ffmpeg package to get the needed software. See [here](http://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media) for details.